# Decreasing of energy functional

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, functional-equations

I read "SADDLE POINTS AND INSTABILITY OF NONLINEAR HYPERBOLIC EQUATIONS" Payne, Sattinger. I have hyperbolic equation:

\begin{equation} \label{eq:intro_main_eq}
 \begin{cases} \tag{A}
  w_{tt}=\Delta w + f(w), x\in \Omega \\
  w\bigr{|}_{\partial \Omega}=0 \\
        u(x,0) = u_0(x),  u_t(x,0) = v_0(x)
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$ w\in W_0^{1,2}, \Omega\in\mathbb{R}^n $.

In fourth part there is energy functional, that decreasing:
$ E(t)=\frac{1}{2} (|u_t|_{L_2}^2+|\nabla u|_{L_2}^2)-\int_D F(u) $, i.e. $\forall t_1, t_2: t_1<t_2<T \Rightarrow E(t_1)\ge E(t_2)$; where $F(u)=\int_0^u f(s)ds$

How can I prove, that this functional is decreasing?

PS To be precise, I can't understand why $\int_{\partial\Omega} u_t \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} $ should be less zero or equal. Or what is my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: If $u$ vanishes on the boundary at all times, then so does $u_t$...

Comment: And energy is constant zero? Is that right?

Comment: Could someone help me?

Comment: Ok, energy functional is constant and not decreasing